# How to count the column in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql, impala

I need the count of columns in hive ,So below is the example.

Table_name:**emp**

columns:
**empno,
ename,
manager,
dept_id**

Expected output:
4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive (now) supports the [information_schema tables](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.4/using-hiveql/content/hive_query_information_schema.html), so you could do:

```
select count(*)
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'emp'
```

Comment: Do we have this table "information_schema.columns" in hive?

Comment: I dont have  information_schema.columns in hive.I need sql query without this pre-defined tables.

Comment: @Rocky . . . Follow the link for information about `information_schema` in Hive.